# Помогите понять смысл mov qword ptr ss:[rsp+20],rbx

Tags: ассемблер

Я понял так. Мы записываем значение из rbx в оперативную память по адресу rsp+20. Однако что значит ss? И как это выражение будет выглядеть в машинных кодах? Где-то я читал что ассемблер на этапе ассемблирования сам вычислит значение но ведь значение в регистре rsp ему неизвестно, тогда преобразует ли он это в две инструкции

```
add rsp 20
mov qword ptr [rsp],rbx
```

или я что то не понимаю.

Comment: Ваши 2 инструкции не равнозначны той, что написана в заголовке. ваши инструкции изменят значение rsp и потом запишут по этому адресу. А инструкция в заголовке вычислит адрес rsp+20 и положит значение по этому адресу, но при этом сам регистр rsp не изменится. Процессоры x86 сами умеют вычислять адреса прямо в командах, как регистр, сумма 2 регистров, регистр плюс регистр умноженный на 2, 4 или 8, и все то же самое и еще плюс константа. Это вычисляет не ассемблер, а отдельный блок процессора, который только этим и занимается

Comment: http://dims.karelia.ru/x86/env_4.shtml  обратите внимание на перечисление кодируемых адресов в самом конце статьи и список регистров в середине (среди которых есть и сегментный SS (селектор сегмента стека)). И да в 64bit регистров еще больше

Answer (score 1):

Это помещение значения из rbx на стек, потому что ss - Stack Segmet как раз. В две инструкции преобразования не будет, потому что имеется тип адресации относительно регистра, который в данном случае и будет использован.